# Need a div to be 100% height of a given area but not overflow the body

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile and I have two main requirements:

1. the main content body will be a huge graphic that should take up the
   entire page and then have scroll (both horizontal and vertical) if it overflows
2. the header must be fixed in place at the top and if screen is rotated fill to expand

So inside of my `ui-content` `div`, I put a div with the following properties

`<div style="position: absolute; height: 100%;width:100%;top:42px;border:0;overflow:auto;">`

The problem is this div is still too big and so the `body` scrollbar is displayed as well as this div's (two scrollbars on the vertical plane).

Here's a jsfiddle of what I have (**two** vertical scrollbars,  one horizonal scrollbar)

http://jsfiddle.net/jN9r3/

Here is a pic of what Im trying to do. (**one** vertical scrollbar, one horizonal scrollbar)

[image]

Comment: Im terrible confused by this, can you show us what you want to have happen in a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: But if I could show what I want to have happen I wouldn't need to post this :c

Comment: Set header to data-position="fixed" and use this article to size the content div to device: http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/06/content-div-height-fill-page-height/

Comment: I added a jsfiddle of what I have to my question

Comment: here is your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/jN9r3/1/

Answer (score -1):

Add `overflow-x:hidden;` to the div that is overflowing. This will stop the horizontal scrolling that you are seeing.